# How do I kill a runing fortran code from inside a shell script that access the same code?

Tags: command-line, scripts, kill, fortran

I have to use a FORTRAN code which has a "menu style" interface. I access the code typing a command on the terminal which opens the main menu. From that point and beyond I type a number and enter it to choose an option that either opens a submenu or executes a command. To exit I have to navigate back to main menu and type "0" to end the code and "get back to terminal". For example, on the terminal I type:

`code_command %` opens the FORTRAN code main menu

`1` → I choose option 1 from main menu, which opens a submenu ;

`2` → From that submenu 1, I choose another submenu by typing option 2;

`7` → From inside this second submenu, I choose the 7th option that does the required task.

`0` → I get back from the second submenu

`0` → I get back from the the first submenu (to the main menu).

`0` → I leave the code and get back to the terminal

So I've written a list of commands that I had to type in order to do a certain task and saved this text as a "script.sh", to make the code execute this list I type:

```
code_command < script.sh
```

Finally, It executes all the lines perfectly except for the last one, when it crashes so I have to open other terminal and type:

```
pkill code_command
```

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> from inside the crashed terminal window.

Is there a way to program a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>  in the `script.sh`,  to kill the running code before it crashes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using bash though this works for the sh and csh too.

First: Set the ulimit core to non-zero (so that you can create a core dump). `man bash` and search for ulimit. `ulimit -c <max size of core dump>`.  The bash default is NO core dump and it must be re-entered every time a new window is opened or new session is started.

Second: Run your program and in another window `kill -3 <pid>` to see if the programs is still running and and get a core dump.  See `man 7 signal` and the "SIGQUIT" or "-3" option.

Third. Use `gdb` to see the statement that caused the problem.  You will have to compile the program using with the "-g" option. `gdb <fortran executable name> core`.  `gdb` can be used to debug interactively.  (And is way beyond the question you asked).

From what you mentioned in your question, you are not handling the EOF correctly for "< input" or stdin and is not exiting out of command loop and stopping.  Or you are in an endless loop or waiting for input in a submenu. The `kill -3 <pid>` finally kills the process EXACTLY where it is hung.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> is suspending the running fortran program. The executable is still running when it hangs.  If you enter the command `fg` for foreground, the fortran program would continue from where it was before the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.